# Why I can't answer command prompt (It just skips to new section before I am able to type y to accept)?

Tags: android, flutter, sdk, command-prompt, android-licenses

I just run flutter doctor to accept android licenses but the command prompt ain't letting me answer. Here is the screenshot I took. I am genuinely confused.
[image]

Comment: Maybe you copied the command with additional 'enter' at the end?

Comment: Please tell me then, what should I click after copying the command if its not enter?

Comment: Just try writing without copying - there is really no much place for an error

Comment: Thanks for bearing this problem with me, but I did try to write the command manually and the result is still the same. It just skips to new section without giving me any chance to input (y/N).

Comment: Finally, I just solved this problem by spamming y and enter after running the command, in order to outpace the command prompt before automatically make a new line